# Wordpress response '0' from server

Tags: jquery, ajax, wordpress, plugins

I am using http://www.garyc40.com/2010/03/5-tips-for-using-ajax-in-wordpress/ as a guide to create a form for users to fill out information and then it creates a post inside of a custom post type. While I get my long string of alerted to me, I always get a response of "0" from the server. Any help with this?

**My plugin file php:**

```
function ajaxurl() {
wp_enqueue_script( 'my-ajax-request', plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ ) . 'js/ajax.js', array( 'jquery' ) );
    wp_localize_script( 'my-ajax-request', 'MyAjax', array(
    // URL to wp-admin/admin-ajax.php to process the request
    'ajaxurl'          => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ),

    // generate a nonce with a unique ID "myajax-post-comment-nonce"
    // so that you can check it later when an AJAX request is sent
    'postCommentNonce' => wp_create_nonce( 'myajax-post-comment-nonce' ),
    )
);
}
add_action('wp_head', 'ajaxurl');
// if both logged in and not logged in users can send this AJAX request,
// add both of these actions, otherwise add only the appropriate one
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_myajax-submit', 'myajax_submit' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_myajax-submit', 'myajax_submit' );

function myajax_submit() {
    $nonce = $_POST['postCommentNonce'];

    // check to see if the submitted nonce matches with the
    // generated nonce we created earlier
    if ( ! wp_verify_nonce( $nonce, 'myajax-post-comment-nonce' ) )
        die ( 'Busted!');

    // get the submitted parameters
    $postID = $_POST['postID'];   

    if ( isset($_post['post_ID']) ) {

    };


    //Create Post from post data
    $newpost = array(
        'post_title' => $_POST['title'],
        'post_author' => $_POST['author'],
        'post_type' => 'assets',
        'post_content' => $_POST['description'],
        'post_category' => $_POST['category']

    );

    //Actually Create the post
    $post_id = wp_insert_post($newpost);

    //now that we have an ID we can add the post meta
    update_post_meta($post_id ,'key', $_POST['key']);



update_post_meta($post_id ,'assetname', $_POST['assetname']);

update_post_meta($post_id ,'assetadd1', $_POST['assetadd1']);
update_post_meta($post_id ,'assetadd2', $_POST['assetadd2']);
update_post_meta($post_id ,'assetcity', $_POST['assetcity']); 
update_post_meta($post_id ,'assetstate', $_POST['assetstate']);    
update_post_meta($post_id ,'assetzipcode', $_POST['assetzipcode']);
update_post_meta($post_id ,'assetlocation', $_POST['assetlocation']);



    // generate the response
    $response = json_encode( array( 'success' => true ) );

    // response output
    header( "Content-Type: application/json" );
    echo $response;
    die();

    // IMPORTANT: don't forget to "exit"
    exit;
}
```

**My jQuery:**
For some reason, the jquery won't fire unless I add the $(document).ready piece

```
$(document).ready(function () {

jQuery('#myForm').submit(function() {


data = $(this).serialize();
data = data + "&postCommentNonce=" + MyAjax.postCommentNonce + "&action=myajax_submit";
alert( data );
```

Up to this point, everything is working. I get my long string of inputs from my form input fields

```
jQuery.post(
    MyAjax.ajaxurl,
    data,
    function( response ) {
        alert( response );
    }
);


return false;

});
});
```

After everything, I'm still only getting a response of "0" form the server every time. Any help on this would be much appreciated.

Comment: Found on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14357762/numeric-response-from-a-post-request-is-adding-a-0

You must write exit; after your echo statements